# Can the complete elliptic integrals of the third kind to be expressed in series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elliptic-integrals

Can the complete elliptic integrals of the third kind which are [defined](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2) by

$$ \Pi (\eta,κ)=\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta  \frac {1}{\sqrt{1−κ \sin^2\theta}} \frac{1}{1 -ηsin^2\theta }$$

to be expressed in series?
Like the fist kind:
$$ F(κ ,\pi/2 ) = \frac{\pi}{2}(1 + (\frac{1}{2})^2 κ^2 + (\frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4})^4 κ^4 + (\frac{1 \cdot 3  \cdot 5 }{2 \cdot 4  \cdot 6})^6 κ^6 ...)  $$
or the second kind:
$$ E(κ ,\pi/2 ) = \frac{\pi}{2}(1 - (\frac{1}{2})^2 κ^2 - (\frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4})^4 \frac{κ^4}{3} + (\frac{1 \cdot 3  \cdot 5 }{2 \cdot 4  \cdot 6})^6 \frac{κ^6}{5} ...)  $$

Comment: There are several series representations given in https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticPi/introductions/CompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html.

Comment: See 19.5.4 at https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.5  Note their $k$ is $\sqrt{\kappa}$ for your $\kappa$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the Taylor series in two dimensions. For example, you could write
$$\Pi (\eta |\kappa )=\sum_{m=0}^{n} P_m(\kappa)\, \eta^m+O(\eta^{n+1})$$ and
$$P_m(\kappa)=\sum_{p=0}^{q} Q_p\, \kappa^p+O(\kappa^{q+1})$$ For example, using $n=q=4$

$$\Pi (\eta |\kappa )=\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{\pi  \kappa }{8}+\frac{9 \pi  \kappa ^2}{128}+\frac{25
   \pi  \kappa ^3}{512}+\frac{1225 \pi  \kappa ^4}{32768}+O\left(\kappa
   ^5\right)\right)+$$ $$\eta  \left(\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{3 \pi  \kappa }{32}+\frac{15
   \pi  \kappa ^2}{256}+\frac{175 \pi  \kappa ^3}{4096}+\frac{2205 \pi  \kappa
   ^4}{65536}+O\left(\kappa ^5\right)\right)+$$ $$\eta ^2 \left(\frac{3 \pi
   }{16}+\frac{5 \pi  \kappa }{64}+\frac{105 \pi  \kappa ^2}{2048}+\frac{315 \pi 
   \kappa ^3}{8192}+\frac{8085 \pi  \kappa ^4}{262144}+O\left(\kappa
   ^5\right)\right)+$$ $$\eta ^3 \left(\frac{5 \pi }{32}+\frac{35 \pi  \kappa
   }{512}+\frac{189 \pi  \kappa ^2}{4096}+\frac{1155 \pi  \kappa
   ^3}{32768}+\frac{15015 \pi  \kappa ^4}{524288}+O\left(\kappa
   ^5\right)\right)+$$ $$\eta ^4 \left(\frac{35 \pi }{256}+\frac{63 \pi  \kappa
   }{1024}+\frac{693 \pi  \kappa ^2}{16384}+\frac{2145 \pi  \kappa
   ^3}{65536}+\frac{225225 \pi  \kappa ^4}{8388608}+O\left(\kappa
   ^5\right)\right)+O\left(\eta ^5\right)$$  For example, suing the above for $\eta=\frac 12$ and $\kappa =\frac 13$ would give $2.46720$ while the exact value is $2.49525$.

Comment: Can you write how it is expressed $Q_p$?

Answer (score 2):

In Maple's notation,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\kappa\, \left( \sin \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}} \left( 1-\eta\, \left( \sin \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \right) }}\,{\rm d}t={\Pi} \left( \eta,\sqrt 
{\kappa} \right) 
\\ &=
{\frac {\pi}{2}{\mbox{$_1$F$_0$}({\frac{1}{2}};\,\ ;\,\eta)}}+{\frac 
{\pi}{2^3}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac{3}{2}};\,2;\,\eta)}}\kappa+{\frac {
3^2\,\pi}{2^7}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac{5}{2}};\,3;\,\eta)}}{\kappa}^{2
}+{\frac {5^2\,\pi}{2^9}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac{7}{2}};\,4;\,\eta)}}
{\kappa}^{3}
\\ &
+{\frac {35^2\,\pi}{2^{15}}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac{9}{2}};\,5;\,\eta)}}{\kappa}^{4}+{\frac {
63^2\,\pi}{2^{17}}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac{11}{2}};\,6;\,\eta)}}{
\kappa}^{5}+{\frac {231^2\,\pi}{2^{21}}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac{13}{2}};\,7;\,\eta)}}{\kappa}^{6}
\\ &
+O
 \left( {\kappa}^{7} \right)
\\ &=
{\frac {\pi}{2}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\eta}}}}+{\frac {\pi}{8} \left( -2
\,{\eta}^{-1}+2\,{\frac {1}{\eta\,\sqrt {1-\eta}}} \right) }\kappa+{
\frac {9\,\pi}{128} \left( -{\frac {4\,\eta+8}{3\,{\eta}^{2}}}+{\frac 
{8}{3\,{\eta}^{2}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\eta}}}} \right) }{\kappa}^{2}
\\&+
{
\frac {25\,\pi}{512} \left( -{\frac {6\,{\eta}^{2}+8\,\eta+16}{5\,{
\eta}^{3}}}+{\frac {16}{5\,{\eta}^{3}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\eta}}}}
 \right) }{\kappa}^{3}
\\&+
{\frac {1225\,\pi}{32768} \left( -{\frac {40\,{
\eta}^{3}+48\,{\eta}^{2}+64\,\eta+128}{35\,{\eta}^{4}}}+{\frac {128}{
35\,{\eta}^{4}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\eta}}}} \right) }{\kappa}^{4}
\\&+
{
\frac {3969\,\pi}{131072} \left( -{\frac {70\,{\eta}^{4}+80\,{\eta}^{3
}+96\,{\eta}^{2}+128\,\eta+256}{63\,{\eta}^{5}}}+{\frac {256}{63\,{
\eta}^{5}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\eta}}}} \right) }{\kappa}^{5}
\\&+
{\frac {
53361\,\pi}{2097152} \left( -{\frac {252\,{\eta}^{5}+280\,{\eta}^{4}+
320\,{\eta}^{3}+384\,{\eta}^{2}+512\,\eta+1024}{231\,{\eta}^{6}}}+{
\frac {1024}{231\,{\eta}^{6}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-\eta}}}} \right) }{
\kappa}^{6}
\\&+O \left( {\kappa}^{7} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: Using Mathematica convention:
$$\Pi(n,m)=\frac\pi2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}\right)^2{}_2F_1(1,k+1/2;k+1;n)m^k$$